# How to sort only usb keys?

Tags: 20.04, regex

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04

what if i want to sort only the usb keys to have an output that would be like this.

usb key name / size Gb / path to the usb key

I tried this but I have both the hard drives and the usb keys.

```
df -ah | awk '/media/{print $1, $2, $6}'
```

or this which is better

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id | grep [a-z]$ | awk '/usb/{print $9, $11}'
```

and which gives

```
usb-Intuix_U3_0DF069605361E946-0:0 ../../sdg
usb-Kingston_DataTraveler_2.0_60A44C3FAD9EFE41E98E256A-0:0 ../../sdf
usb-_USB_DISK_3.0_070B84A2C7C19B89-0:0 ../../sdh
usb-Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_1230000000003CFD-0:0 ../../sdi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### About `lsblk`

I suggest using `lsblk`. You find different aspects of this tool via these two commands,

```
lsblk -h
man lsblk
```

### Using your command with `df` and `awk` together with `lsblk`

`hotplug` is used to pick the USB drives.

```
$ lsblk -Po name,size,label,mountpoint,hotplug $(df -ah | awk '/media/{print $1}')|grep 'HOTPLUG="1"'|sed 's/ HOTPLUG="1"//'
NAME="sdc1" SIZE="29,5G" LABEL="usbdata" MOUNTPOINT="/media/olle/usbdata"
NAME="sdd1" SIZE="10G" LABEL="isodevice" MOUNTPOINT="/media/olle/isodevice"
```

### Using `lsblk` twice, first to identify the USB drives, then listing partitions

`tran` is used to pick the USB drives.

```
$ for i in $(lsblk -dPo name,tran|grep 'TRAN="usb"'|cut -d \" -f2);do echo '-----';lsblk -lo name,size,label,mountpoint,vendor,model /dev/$i;done
-----
NAME  SIZE LABEL   MOUNTPOINT          VENDOR   MODEL
sdc  29,5G                             Corsair  Voyager GT 3.0  
sdc1 29,5G usbdata /media/olle/usbdata          
-----
NAME   SIZE LABEL     MOUNTPOINT            VENDOR   MODEL
sdd   29,1G                                 Kingston DT Workspace    
sdd1    10G isodevice /media/olle/isodevice          
sdd2   977K                                          
sdd3 244,1M usbboot
```

Answer (score 0):

This should provide mapping between those two USB output examples:

```
# for usbdrv in $(df -ah | awk '$6 ~ /^\/media\// {print $1";"$2";"$6}'); do echo "${usbdrv}"; Dev=$(echo "${usbdrv}" | awk -F";" '{print $1}' | sed 's#/dev/##');  usbID=$(basename $(ls -al /dev/disk/by-id/usb* 2>&1 | grep ${Dev} | awk '{print $9}') 2>/dev/null); echo "${usbID};${usbdrv}"|sed 's/;/ /g'; done | column -t
```

Comment: Please see my answer. If it solves the problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks

Comment: at the end just add grep usb to have only usb drive